# How we can access to nested class in an aggregate

Tags: c#, .net, aggregate, domain-driven-design

I have these classes:

```
    public class Area{
...
       private List<WorkSpace> _workspace;
       public IReadOnlyCollection<WorkSpace> workspace;
}
```

and

```
public class WorkSpace{
   ...
   private List<WorkSpaceReservation> _workspaceReservation;
   public IReadOnlyCollection<WorkSpaceReservation> workspaceReservation;
}
```

and

```
  public class WorkSpaceReservation{
    ...
       
    }
```

Area is the aggregate root.
Now I want to add `WorkSpaceReservation` to WorkSpaceReservation list. Is it possible in DDD context and rules to define a method in workspace like this:

```
public void AddWorkSpaceReservation(WorkSpaceReservation w){
_workspaceReservation.Add(w);
}
```

Or we should add this method in aggregate root?
If for isolation, we should add it in aggregate root how can I access to `_workspaceReservation` from aggregate root?

Comment: If you want it done through Area, you would need to pass both workspace and item to add and area would need a mutable interface towards workspace.

Comment: @Fildor So do you think it's better to be in WorkSpace?

Comment: I don't know your project, environment nor requirements, so the decision is still up to you. Just telling you what _would_ be needed if you wanted to go that way.

Comment: @Fildor I know. My mean is in context of DDD. Is it possible to Add from a class that is not aggregate root.

Comment: I really can't give advice on DDD. Not my field of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) to avoid having the method in the `Workspace` but as you mentioned add it in the `Area`.

Having mutations in the aggregate root allows to implement invariants (validation) that can take into account the state of the entire aggregate, instead of just the single entity.

But doing it or not could not have a big impact depending what you need to do, more important is that also if the method is on the `Workspace` you don't allow the `Workspace` itself to be persisted, but only the aggregate root can be.

To solve the issue of the `_workspaceReservation` field I think you have to do something with the access modifiers (maybe having it `internal`?), but don't know much of C#

Comment: About internal(or others) it can been access to it by other aggregates in the same namespace.

Comment: So you mean both of them are possible to add in aggregate root and workspace?

Comment: From a "DDD point of view" when you have to modify an aggregate you should always pass from the aggregate root, then having an `addWorkspaceReservation` in the root or having a `getWorkspaces()` to get the list of entities and then having `addWorkspaceReservation` to the internal aggregate doesn't change too much (a part from eventual changes that needs to be propagated in case the structure of the aggregate root change).

Comment: About the access modifier it is more a language concern than DDD, as I see it you can also have the mutable list public in the entity, the important thing is that it is not mutated outside of a method of the entities themself